# how to use __init__ circular error when launching app.py in dash app

Tags: python, plotly-dash

This is my structure

```
app/
  assets/
  data/
  __init__.py
  app.py
  figures.py
  template.py
  requirements.txt
```

my **init**.py:

```
import dash
import dash_auth
USERNAME_PASSWORD_PAIRS = [['xx','xx']]
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output

from app.languages import app_en, app_fr

app = dash.Dash(__name__, meta_tags=[
    {'name': 'viewport', 'content': 'width=device-width'},
    {'name': 'description', 'content': 'Well-being survey dashboard / Tableau de bord Enquete Bien Etre'},
])
app.title = 'Well-being survey dashboard'
app.config.suppress_callback_exceptions = True
auth = dash_auth.BasicAuth(app,USERNAME_PASSWORD_PAIRS)

# WSGI entry point
server = app.server


app.layout = html.Div([
    dcc.Location(id='url', refresh=False),
    html.Div(id='page-content')
])


@app.callback(Output('page-content', 'children'),
              [Input('url', 'pathname')])
def display_page(pathname):
    if pathname == '/':
        return app_fr.layout
    elif pathname == '/fr':
        return app_fr.layout
    elif pathname == '/en':
        return app_en.layout
    else:
        return '404: Page Not Found'
```

app.py

```
from __init__ import app

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=False)
```

template.py : I've to import figures and the only way found is : import app.figures as figures
for me it is weird because I should do .figures as figures ...

My error is when launching app.py:

from **init** import app
ImportError: cannot import name 'app' from partially initialized module '**init**' (most likely due to a circular import) (/Users/philippehaumesser/PycharmProjects/bienetre/app/**init**.py)

Comment: Should that be `from . import app` ?

Comment: I already tried but error is:    from . import app
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package

Comment: I tried to delete __init__.py and put his code in app.py but same issue:     from app.languages import app_en, app_fr
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'app.languages'; 'app' is not a package

Comment: Don't delete `__init__.py`, just leave it as an empty file. Python needs that to know that the `app ` directory is a Python module. If you move the code into `app.py`, then I bet this works fine.

Answer (score 0):

thanks to coral vanda, I just add **init**.py file in all my subfolders and it works.
thanks